# $.post() not working if the mvc model view controller has a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I´m new with MVC. I´m using MVC4.
I'm having an issue with a callback. If I alert before and after the post() call both alerts show but the call doesn't fire.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Dashboard(int Menu)
{
 //some code
 return View("Dashboard");
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("../Client/GetFact", {},
        function (data) {  
          //some code
        });
    });
</script> 

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetFact()
{
    //some code to fill object_data

    var data = object_data;

    return Json(data);
}
```

As long as I leave ActionResult Dashboard without a parameter is works. If I add a parameter to Dashboard(int Menu) then the call back to GetFact doesn't work. 
I searched and found a similar post and follow the instructions given by you guys, but still does not work( looked at: getJSON not working if the mvc model view controller has a parameter).
I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Can you help? Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar with $.get, using jquery with the @Url.Action instead of the url.

in addition to using the FormContext to pass to my Action :

Place just before @using (Html.BeginForm())

```
@{ ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); }
```

example :

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")', { IDName: $('#IdName').val() }, function (data) {
                    //Do Something here with the data
                });
```

I would imagine form post would be

```
$.post('@Url.Ation("ActionName", "ControllerName")', function (data) {
                     //Do Something here with the data
              });
```

Comment: BTW: How are you accessing Dashboard?  with a $.get call?  or through the URL?

Comment: Thank you all.:) the solution you gave me "$.post('@Url.Ation("ActionName", "ControllerName")'..." worked fine.

Comment: not a problem...its what i use to create a lot of nice user dynamic content, without constantly refreshing a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({  type: "POST",
           url: url,  
          data: data,
       success: success,// -> call alert here  
      dataType: dataType});
```